# Proving two graphs have the same chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G= (V,E)$ be a graph, and let $G'= (V',E')$ be a copy of $G$.  That is, for each $v ∈ V$ there  is  a  corresponding $v' ∈ V'$ and  for  each  edge  $(u,v)∈E$ there  is  a  corresponding edge $(u',v')∈E'$.  Construct a graph $G\widehat{}$ by drawing an edge from each $v∈V$ to its corresponding $v'∈V'$.  Prove that $\chi (G\widehat{}) =\chi (G)$.

My work: I sketched a few graphs such that they could be colored using two color and drew $G$ and $G'$ for each. By construction it's apparent that $G\widehat{}$ could also be colored using two colors. But i'm having a hard time extending this to more than two colors and actually writing down a proof, as a picture doesn't really count as proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the new graph $\hat{G}$ is just two copies of $G$ with the corresponding vertices connected right? If so, just think about permuting the colors on the second copy. Explicitly, say you colored $V$ with the colors $\{1, 2, \ldots k\}$. Then for $v'\in V'$, if the corresponding $v\in V$ has color $i$ color $v'$ with $i+1 \mod k$.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I understand what you're saying but how do I connect it to χ(Gˆ)?

Comment: Well you colored all the vertices in $\hat{G}$ with the same colors as $G$, so the chromatic numbers are the same. That is, if you colored $G$ with $\{ 1,2, \ldots k\}$ then the above explains how to color $\hat{G}$ with  $\{ 1,2, \ldots k\}$ also.

Comment: Note that (a) $\chi (G\widehat{})$ is at least $\chi(G)$ as there is a subgraph of $G\widehat{}$ isomorphic to $G$. Yet @Edgar Jaramillo Rodriguez gave a proper coloring of $G\widehat{}$ using only $\chi(G)$ colors, this implies that (b) $\chi (G\widehat{})$ is also no more than $\chi(G)$, so (a) and (b) together imply equality.

Comment: So $\chi(\hat{G}) \geq \chi(G)$ since every coloring of $G$ admits a coloring of $\hat{G}$ with the same number of colors. But at the same time $\chi(\hat{G}) \leq \chi(G)$ since any coloring of $\hat{G}$ contains a coloring of $G$ in its subgraph. So in fact $\chi(\hat{G}) =\chi(G)$

Comment: @Mike we have not covered isomorphisms in class so could you explain what you mean in a way that doesn't require understanding of isomorphisms, please?

Comment: I can rewrite the first sentence of my last comment: Note that (a) $\chi (G\widehat{})$ is at least $\chi(G)$, as $G$ that is a subgraph of $\chi (G\widehat{})$ is at least $\chi(G)$. But getting back to "isomorphism", the graphs $G$ and $G'$ are [by definition of "isomorphic"], isomorphic to each other.